# How to catch hover on div elements?

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` in which  are `div`, `img`, `a`, `h3`, `input` elements. They dynamically changing (carousel). So i need to stop `setInterval` which provides this changes on hover, but it doesn't work (`hover` event doesn't fire).

```
jQuery('div.slider').on('hover', 'div, img, a, h3, input',
//Tried jQuery('body').on('hover', 'div.slider'...
//Alsro tried on('focusin focusout')
    function(event){
        console.log('on');
        if(event.type === 'focusin'){
            console.log(event.type);
            stopCarousel();
        }
        else if(event.type === 'focusout'){
            console.log(event.type);
            startCarousel();
        }
    }
);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Where is the HTML? `jsfiddle` please?

Comment: Hover uses mouseenter - mouseleave event  http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.hover()`, is a function not an event, and it uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so it most certainly will not have a type that matches focusin or focusout. I'd just do:

```
$('div.slider').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        stopCarousel();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        startCarousel();
   }
}, 'div, img, a, h3, input');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the event you are looking for is not `hover` but `mouseover`.

In pure Javascript no `hover` event exists. Hover is the conclusion `mouseover` which begins an hover and `mouseout` which stops the hover event. In you case `mouseover` should be the event you are looking for.

Comment: Would you care to explain why and maybe add some code... this way it's not really enough to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.slider').mouseenter(function (event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    stopCarousel();
});

$('.slider').mouseleave(function (event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    startCarousel();
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/ and http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: This is **not** a delegated event handler, and does not work on dynamic elements ?

Comment: @adeneo: `event.type` [exists](http://jsfiddle.net/wS4j4/), OP wanted to log it so I added it.  As for the dynamic elements, if the slider class is on the containing div, then `.on` isn't required because its never changing, the elements inside it are.  OP never specified if he wanted it to stop for a mouseover on the entire slider or only a mouseover on the specific elements inside.